# c - struct - what does the additional ": 1" doing?

Tags: c, struct

What is the " : 1" part doing in following code?

**code:**

```
struct trace_key {
        const char * const key;
        int fd; 
        unsigned int initialized : 1;
        unsigned int  need_close : 1;
};
```

Comment: Refer `Bitfields` in C programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [bit field in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm).

You probably don't want to use them much these days (since accessing bit fields is costly, and the memory gain is often negligible, unless you have dozen of millions of `struct trace_key` in memory). In your case you'll better code:

```
struct trace_key {
    const char * const key;
    int fd; 
    bool initialized;
    bool need_close;
};
```

after having added `#include <stdbool.h>` (assuming [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or better)

BTW, on my machine the `sizeof(struct trace_key)` is the same with bit fields or with `bool` in that particular case (since the `struct trace_key` has to be word-aligned, and the end padding is larger than a `bool`)

Comment: Thanks, I will google about that.

Comment: You should also experiment and benchmark.

Comment: Sure, I saw the code from git source trace.h, try to learn c programming by view source code, thank you.

Comment: There is no `bool` in C < 99!

Comment: Ok, but we are in 2014. Who cares about pre99 C standard ?